# Saving CET Date in UTC Format

Tags: java, sql, oracle, datetime, timezone

I have a date in the format `2018-03-19T06:00:00+01:00` which is already in `CET` time.

When I save this in Oracle database column `timestamp` exactly as `CET` and when retrieved again it is showing as `2018-03-19 7:00:00 AM`instead of `2018-03-19 6:00:00 AM`

So I have converted the `CET` to `UTC` and then saving to database and when retrieved it is now displayed correctly.

```
cast(TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2018-03-19T06:00:00+01:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"HH24:mi:ss tzr') at time zone 'UTC' as date
```

Is this the proper way to convert `CET` to `UTC` and then saving in database?

Comment: Is what the proper way?  You haven't shared **any** code.

Comment: Yes Now I have shared, but actually I have asked whether that approach is correct

Comment: What is the data type of your column?

Comment: timestamp data type

Comment: Is the Java tag relevant? You may use `OffsetDateTime.parse("2018-03-19T06:00:00+01:00").toInstant()` and store the obtained `Instant` to the datebase through `PreparedStatement.setObject()` (if using JDBC 4.2 or later).

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks! Is that not the proper way what I have used with oracle functions itself?

Comment: It’s your decision, both approaches are correct. For most uses I might want to keep time zone considerations out of the database, but you may have reasons to do otherwise in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column is `TIMESTAMP` then I would recommend

```
SYS_EXTRACT_UTC( TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ('2018-03-19T06:00:00+01:00','yyyy-mm-dd"T"HH24:mi:ss tzr') )
```